# Is it common practice to combine room and dryer vent ducts?

Tags: exhaust-vent

Is it common practice to tie the exhaust vent to the dryer (gas) vent pipe in laundry room with no windows? I can find no separate pipe for the ceiling fan/vent in the attic .  I am experiencing moisture leaking from fan/vent pipe

Comment: It could also be that the duct is simply not hooked up. When the roof on my house was replaced by the previous owner, the roofer didn't put in a vent cap for the master bathroom exhaust fan. The duct was just hanging loose in my attic.

Comment: Yes, that was a common practice years ago. Very possible.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. Bringing two exhaust vents together that likely have very different pressures is a recipe for failure (and potentially dangerous backflow). They must be vented separately.

Answer (score 0):

Code usually requires separate vents for bathrooms etc. and a clothes dryer. You now know why.

Comment: I think that preventing Carbon Monoxide backflow into the house is a more important reason than moisture -- excessive moisture entering the house can be a problem over the long term, but CO is an immediate threat to health and can be fatal.